# How can I separate each of 100 observations into groups as determined by the data?

Tags: r, clustering, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have 3 covariates for 100 observations. How can I separate each of my 100 observations into groups as determined by the data. I was thinking clustering. However, apparently, I need more than 3 dimensions to do hierarchical clustering. Would some other clustering method work? How about PCA?

I've attached the data as R output below.

`dput` output

```
structure(c(3.87, 0.672, 0.7392, 6.471, 0.12294, 1.0857, 16.701, 
0.2754, 0.17328, 8.076, 0.12222, 1.1796, 8.625, 1.3998, 0.07233, 
3.933, 0.017484, 0.9189, 4.134, 0.7338, 2.9517, 5.091, 0.017136, 
0.6318, 6.672, 3.012, 0.08214, 15.834, 0.7968, 0.27768, 3.954, 
0.02046, 0.705, 9.465, 0.15444, 1.2702, 15.012, 0.4263, 2.262, 
21.438, 0.9291, 0.3399, 20.076, 1.023, 8.289, 5.601, 0.007992, 
0.984, 12.396, 0.4869, 2.343, 11.697, 0.4296, 0.4932, 8.247, 
0.27063, 0.3408, 3.273, 0.03954, 0.16446, 4.59, 0.0011037, 0.8937, 
11.196, 0.17538, 0.9594, 14.688, 0.13527, 0.3672, 2.8554, 0.0027594, 
0.5943, 0.26472, 0.0004233, 0.3315, 1.5633, 0.0363, 0.5232, 5.766, 
0.005901, 0.342, 10.578, 2.4477, 0.28872, 10.803, 1.0185, 1.3935, 
5.352, 1.1967, 0.5316, 4.8, 0.00672, 2.6418, 3.081, 0.15525, 
0.6873, 13.899, 0.19149, 0.4674, 11.439, 1.6521, 0.3867, 4.005, 
0.008328, 0.3675, 5.7, 0.027999, 0.3486, 13.035, 0.21639, 0.7293, 
8.706, 1.0833, 0.198, 5.871, 0.5655, 2.0367, 4.218, 0.011547, 
0.24234, 2.1603, 0.0011748, 0.4569, 5.385, 0.005091, 0.666, 9.651, 
0.4392, 1.101, 11.178, 0.4179, 0.7005, 8.151, 0.00516, 0.27696, 
6.864, 0.018753, 0.303, 3.792, 0.01449, 1.8345, 6.834, 0.03339, 
0.28896, 5.073, 0.012951, 0.5013, 3.132, 0.008892, 0.3207, 1.1841, 
5.292e-05, 0.006795, 9.432, 0.324, 0.5916, 8.55, 2.4642, 0.9576, 
3.588, 0.006912, 1.089, 6.396, 0.04818, 1.4448, 20.604, 0.363, 
0.7401, 11.712, 0.03897, 1.9491, 11.682, 1.149, 2.217, 3.882, 
0.15963, 5.916, 6.702, 0.3174, 1.6392, 7.188, 0.03582, 0.2646, 
8.853, 0.7761, 2.2446, 18.915, 0.3993, 0.002736, 9.699, 0.16638, 
0.6855, 9.423, 0.011793, 0.7986, 14.667, 2.5146, 0.28512, 5.919, 
0.06705, 0.25305, 8.184, 0.005262, 0.6492, 1.4604, 0.0138, 0.1872, 
8.604, 0.3057, 0.8052, 8.142, 0.017808, 0.9564, 2.2824, 0.000243, 
0.2565, 6.012, 0.16425, 0.3969, 12.633, 0.9408, 1.7154, 9.396, 
0.21945, 2.73, 13.479, 0.16236, 14.433, 9.612, 0.24222, 1.3275, 
12.486, 2.1543, 0.08652, 0.0003612, 5.364e-07, 0.3144, 9.942, 
1.3674, 1.326, 2.4621, 0.00019425, 0.6684, 1.6341, 0.0006165, 
0.5124, 11.796, 0.9798, 3.243, 11.73, 0.4716, 1.0248, 5.133, 
0.04527, 0.3078, 11.886, 2.6718, 1.158, 5.421, 0.06027, 1.7655, 
6.69, 0.00783, 5.907, 11.832, 0.9534, 3.228, 1.0323, 0.0016356, 
0.861, 6.774, 1.1001, 1.1811, 8.856, 0.4185, 1.3521, 11.877, 
0.2754, 2.5563, 0.0024852, 1.4796e-05, 0.6741, 6.774, 0.336, 
2.5017, 1.6425, 2.478e-05, 0.09243, 8.973, 0.25473, 0.9942, 13.245, 
0.3234, 0.6711, 10.35, 0.5148, 1.0578, 14.556, 0.774, 0.9225), .Dim = c(3L, 
100L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("000162434", "000151547", 
"000133688", "000123954", "000184599", "000122987", "000117559", 
"000121528", "000192459", "000196759", "000172539", "000155583", 
"000185889", "000143968", "000128617", "000185423", "000158324", 
"000114797", "000126134", "000185624", "000123385", "000188299", 
"000195142", "000194666", "000113189", "000182457", "000173324", 
"000162459", "000141996", "000155516", "000148231", "000176159", 
"000135131", "000186287", "000187355", "000199513", "000125251", 
"000116237", "000188675", "000147224", "000198156", "000119366", 
"000132841", "000123791", "000138154", "000149758", "000157127", 
"000167763", "000113718", "000128418", "000148221", "000139836", 
"000194814", "000199972", "000168968", "000198853", "000128498", 
"000149484", "000196219", "000184178", "000144155", "000114251", 
"000114264", "000131697", "000154146", "000163257", "000112289", 
"000114416", "000195761", "000128348", "000144337", "000167126", 
"000159175", "000172296", "000182932", "000198134", "000127718", 
"000166651", "000196877", "000174415", "000131167", "000165476", 
"000195958", "000189229", "000119255", "000165984", "000119118", 
"000164273", "000199986", "000136544", "000124271", "000191248", 
"000126459", "000143728", "000182847", "000162785", "000193387", 
"000119516", "000199516", "000145424")))
```

Comment: wow... Seriously man, remove the data points from the question...

Comment: I would start with a 3d plot of your 3 covariates to make sure visually that there are clusters

Comment: @Bitwise: why? For once that someone gives a `dput` he should rather be congratulated!

Comment: @nico well it looks better now after editing, it was a mess before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bitwise mentions, clustering should be fine.
Given your data matrix, you will need to transpose first:

```
data <- t(data)
hc <- hclust(dist(data))
plot(hc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you want clustering. The simplest ones to start with are kmeans or hierarchical clustering. There shouldn't be any limit on dimensionality - you can even cluster 1D data.

Answer (score 0):

Why should it not work fewer dimensions. Actually a common use case for clustering is geo/map data, which is typically 2d data. You can cluster 1d, but there are better algorithms from statistics for 1d data (which, in contrast to 2d, is completely ordered).

**Just try it**!